# Material-ui Grid: Grid item's width too big and going outside of Grid container

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to set up a simple layout for a SPA using Material-ui and React. My idea is to have a left hand column as a sidebar and a right-hand main area to render information etc. However, in my current set-up I have two issues:
The `<Grid item>` and its container `<Button>` elements extend beyond the left sidebard `<Grid container item xs={3} className={classes.sideBarGrid}>` into the right hand column. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bjp14)

Also, I cannot get the right hand grid column `<Grid container item xs={9} className={classes.labelGrid}>` get to work to be full width, even though I set it to `width: "100%"`.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  mainContainer: {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh"
  },
  labelGrid: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#EBEDF0",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%"
  },
  sideBarGrid: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },

  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  labelarea: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  imagearea: {
    minHeight: 200
  },
  classButton: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  commentField: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 2, 3)
  }
}));

export default function Labelscreen(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  // history for react router

  // array with potential classes for image
  const buttonText = ["one", "two"];

  // function to filter list of labels by property and see if object property is null

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.mainContainer}>
      <CssBaseline />

      <Grid container item xs={3} className={classes.sideBarGrid}>
        <Grid item>
          {buttonText.map((item, key) => (
            <Button
              className={classes.classButton}
              variant="outlined"
              color="primary"
              fullWidth
            >
              {item} ({key + 1})
            </Button>
          ))}

          <TextField
            id="imageComment"
            label="Comment"
            placeholder="please put comments here"
            multiline
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            value="adfljdaf"
          />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Go back
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={9} className={classes.labelGrid}>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Something
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

The gray area on the right hand does not fill the whole screen when the screen size is large, even though the `width` is set to 100% in the `labelGrid`

[image: Gray box behind 'something' text should go all the way to the right edge]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part about the right-side 100% width, but you got the answer on the other parts. Please explain the right-side part.

Comment: Thank you for solving the first part of my question. I edited above question to specify my second question. Basically, I want the right box to go full width and I am confused why it is not happening with `width:100%`.

Comment: The reason that the right-box does not go full width is that the structure that you are looking for doesn't play nice with the grid-structure. You should use grid when you want to split the page to known number of columns (and known width/%). This is not exactly your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your buttons have margin (right & left), so they move beyond your left sidebar.
   You can fix this using:

```
  classButton: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1, 0)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1, 0)
  },
```

2. To add back the space on the left&right side you can add padding on the container:

```
  sideBarGrid: {
    maxWidth: 300,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1)
  },
```